# I have a problem with my minesweeper project

Tags: c

I made a minesweeper but I have a problem.
I want to show mines by using `*` but it shows `0`.

And this minesweeper never stops even though I point to the location where the mine places.

When I print array `matrixMine[][]` it shows like this.

```
1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 
0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 
0 0 0 0 2 1 0 0 0 
0 0 0 1 2 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 1
0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0
```

What should I do?

I think there is a problem in `createMine()`.

Please ignore the comments.

```c
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void createMine();
void createMap();
void mineMap();
int point();

char matrix[10][10];
char matrixMine[10][10];

int main(void)
{
    createMap();
    printf("Please wait for installing mines.\n");
    createMine();
    mineMap();
    while (point() != 0)
    {
        point();
    }

    return 0;
}

void createMine(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //무작위 위치에 지뢰 10개 만들기
    {
        srand((unsigned int)time(NULL));

        int x = (rand() % 9) + 1;

        int y = (rand() % 9) + 1;

        if (matrixMine[y][x] == '*') //현재 위치에 지뢰가 존재하면 다시 설치함
        {
            --i;
            continue;
        }

        matrixMine[y][x] = '*';
    }
}

void createMap(void)//지뢰찾기 맵 만들기
{

    int i, j, row = 49, col = 49;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = '?';

    }

    matrix[0][0] = (char)32;

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        matrix[i][0] = (char)col;
        col++;
    }

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        matrix[0][i] = (char)row;
        row++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            printf("%c ", matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void mineMap()//주변의 지뢰 갯수 확인
{
    int i, j, counter = 48;

    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            for (int y = i - 1; y <= i + 1; y++) //8방향을 나타내는 for문
            {
                for (int x = j - 1; x < j + 1; x++)
                {
                    if (y < 1 || x < 1 || y>9 || x>9) //만약 맵을 벗어날 경우 지나침
                        continue;
                    if (matrixMine[y][x] == '*') //만약 지뢰일 경우 지뢰일 때마다 counter에 1을 더해줌
                        counter+=1;
                }
            }
            matrixMine[i][j] = (char)counter; //주변에 있는 지뢰의 갯수를 저장
            counter = 48;
        }
    }
}

int point()
{
    int x, y, i, j;

    printf("input point x y \n");
    scanf("%d %d", &y, &x);

    if (matrixMine[y][x] == '*')
    {
        matrix[y][x] = matrixMine[y][x];
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                printf("%c ", matrix[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        printf("GAME OVER");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        matrix[y][x] = matrixMine[y][x];
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 10; j++)
                printf("%c ", matrix[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: OT: call `srand` _only once_ at program startup.

Comment: You should create a [mre]. Function `point` is not related to your problem, so you can remove this and replace the `while(point())` loop with a comment, e.g. `/* removed code to handle player's guesses and display result */`. Instead you should add code that prints `matrixMine` at the various stages to show the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid overwriting the `'*'` in function `mineMap`.

change

```
            matrixMine[i][j] = (char)counter; //주변에 있는 지뢰의 갯수를 저장
```

to

```
            if(matrixMine[i][j] != '*')
            {
                matrixMine[i][j] = (char)counter; //주변에 있는 지뢰의 갯수를 저장
            }
```

---

Additional hints not related to your problem:

Instead of using the character code representing  a number/digit I suggest to use the corresponding character constant.

either

```
    int i, j;
    char counter = '0';

/* ... */

            if(matrixMine[i][j] != '*')
            {
                matrixMine[i][j] = counter; //주변에 있는 지뢰의 갯수를 저장
            }
            counter = '0';
```

or

```
    int i, j, counter = 0;

/* ... */

            if(matrixMine[i][j] != '*')
            {
                matrixMine[i][j] = (char)(counter + '0'); //주변에 있는 지뢰의 갯수를 저장
            }
            counter = 0;
```

In function `point` you should check the return value of `scanf`. If the user types something that cannot be converted to two integer numbers, the variables `x` and `y` can be uninitialized. If the user types more than 2 numbers, the additional number(s) will be used for the next `scanf`.

You have code to print the matrix in 3 places. I suggest to replace this with a function, e.g. `printMatrix`.

In general I suggest to separate the input and output from the processing functions.

Answer (score 0):

In `main`, you call the functions in this order:

```c
    createMine();
    mineMap();
```

The function `createMine` is the one that puts the character '*' in the map. However, after calling `createMine`, you call `mineMap`, which contain this:

```c
    for (i = 1; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (j = 1; j < 10; j++)
        {
            (...)
            matrixMine[i][j] = (char)counter; //주변에 있는 지뢰의 갯수를 저장
            counter = 48;
        }
    }
```

This double for loop effectively erases all the '*' in the map, and replaces them with `(char)counter`.

Suggestion: try calling `createMine` **after** `mineMap` in `main`.